# How would I pass this json.dumps() to a function to use?

Tags: python

How would I pass result to display_function?

```
def some_function ():
    url = "someurl"
    data = requests.get(url).json()
    result = json.dumps(data)
    display_function(result)

def display_function (result): ## get's json.dumps(data) to use and display to html in this function
    output = "some html goes here:" + result 
    return output
```

Comment: Display it in a `<pre>` tag.

Comment: For some reason, result is never getting passed to display_function(). I don't think I'm passing it correctly?

Comment: When `some_function()` calls `display_function()`, it does not save the returned information.  Obviously this is not your real code, so I can't tell if this is the real problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only defining functions, but you never actually call them. You can try rewriting your script like:

```
def some_function ():
    url = "someurl"
    data = requests.get(url).json()
    result = json.dumps(data)
    main_result = display_function(result)
    return main_result

def display_function (result): ## get's json.dumps(data) to use and display to html in this function
    output = "some html goes here:" + result 
    return output

if __name__ == "__main__":
    my_results_wanted = somefunction()
```

You can also test that it is getting passed by adjusting like:

```
def display_function (result): ## get's json.dumps(data) to use and display to html in this function
    print(result) # This will show you what the function is receiving!
    output = "some html goes here:" + result 
    return output
```

Comment: Thank you. Used your example to find what was wrong on my side. It's now working.